# Вопрос по синтаксу LINQ запроса

Tags: linq

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, Обязательно ли указывать from tablename in? Тк на второй картинке такого нет.

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не скрином

Comment: Синтаксис SQL допускает отсутствие в запросе секции FROM. Однако linq не поддерживает скалярные, без источника данных, запросы. Некоторые СУБД в случае скалярных запросов используют секцию-заполнитель `FROM dual` или аналогичную, некоторые не имеют такой "затычки". Однако это нельзя использовать в linq - он не станет работать с "незарегистрированной" таблицей. Впрочем, всегда остаётся возможность использовать Raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Да, указывать это обязательно, так как это является частью синтаксиса.

Стоит так же отметить, что это **не** *from tablename in*, так как после `from` указывается не имя таблицы, а имя объекта соответствующего записи в этой таблице.

Для того чтобы стало понятнее, в примерах нужно заменить `from employee` на `from emp` тогда становится ясно соответствие с синтаксисом методов.

Comment: "имя объекта соответствующего записи в этой таблице" вы имеете ввиду, что в LINQ не типа table, а есть лишь тип object?

Comment: @BillyBob, потому что это часть query синтаксиса. А на второй картинке в виде методов. Ты найдешь соответствие `from nameObj` если сделаешь изменения указанные в ответе.

Comment: @BillyBob, _"имя объекта соответствующего записи в этой таблице" вы имеете ввиду, что в LINQ не типа table, а есть лишь тип object?_ - нет, перечитай еще раз эту строчку.

Comment: @BillyBob, _Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в втором примере не используется from emp in?_ - сделай изменения, описанные в ответе и ответь, как именно `from emp` используется во втором примере.

Comment: Если я правильно понял таблица employees содержится в объекте emp. Тогда в первом случае query = emp.employees а во втором employees, то есть в обоих случаях query будет типа Table?

Comment: @BillyBob, _Если я правильно понял таблица employees содержится в объекте emp._ - ты понял неправильно. `таблица employees` - `emp` - это отдельная строка таблицы

Comment: то есть emp это строка - объект в таблице внутри которого содержится ячейка тоже объект?

Comment: @BillyBob, неа. Это тоже самое, что и тут `Where( emp => ... )`

Comment: Если я правильно понял там две ячейки LName и FName? Если emp это строка

Comment: @BillyBob, ты неправильно понял :-) Возможно тебе стоит начать с более базового уровня

Comment: @BillyBob, ты понимаешь, что происходит на втором скриншоте, и как это работает?

Comment: Вроде как да   понимаю

Comment: @BillyBob, на первом - происходит абсолютно то же самое, и если изменишь название переменной, так как указано в ответе - примеры вообще станут идентичными.

Comment: Если я правильно понял в query возвращаются строки состоящие из двух столбцов FirstName LastName, которые соответствуют условию. Таким образом получаем таблицу

Comment: @BillyBob, что ты имеешь ввиду под `query` здесь и под столбцами и таблицами?

Comment: не понял что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @BillyBob ты написал: _в query возвращаются строки состоящие из двух столбцов_ - что, в данном случае, ты понимаешь под query?

Comment: Даже если вернется одна строка это уже будет таблица так что в любом случае тип query это Table

Comment: @BillyBob, _тип query это Table_ - пока ты не покажешь код, с определением `query` и `Table` - нельзя гарантировать, что тип query это Table. На предоставленных скриншотах явно видно, что это утверждение неверно

Comment: Объясните Для приведенного кода если вернется одна строка состоящая из двух столбцов это будет DataTable или DataRow?

Comment: @BillyBob, ни то, ни другое. В переменной query в примере, не будет ни DataTable, ни DataRow - никогда.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, Что там будет?

Comment: Возможно Object?

Comment: @BillyBob, ты можешь проверить это, наведя указатель мыши на данную переменную, среда разработки подскажет тип переменной. Он не зависит от количества строк в результате.

Comment: Это надо сделать до выполнения кода или после?

Comment: @BillyBob, в любой момент